# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: spring, cxf

I am doing training about CXF and Spring, so I wrote a very simple CXF demo which only has the interface "HelloWorld" and its implementor "HelloWorldWs".

I want to publish it with Tomcat. I wrote a web.xml and applicationContext.xml（Spring profile. Though i can publish the WSDL .But the console list a problem:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/cxf_spring] threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
```

I did not use or write any io function, just a "sayhi" function. I am stumped.

Comment: Difficult to help without any code. Can you post some?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug and is fixed as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5620,
CXF 2.7.11 (released)